# Installing Bugjar - the GUI debugger for Python

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7

I have come across this issue multiple times

The instructions for installing and running bugjar are just the following:

```
$ pip install bugjar  
$ bugjar myscript.py arg1 arg2
```

I never understood what that dollar sign stands for?

I am using Python(x,y) 2.7 and I managed to run the pip install bugjar in iPython shell (I don't know what a shell is, I usually run and write my code in Spyder; but that particular command would not run in Spyder).

And now I do not know how to initiate the GUI debugger. I tried to run bugjar test.py in that same shell, though it does not work. It appears that I have to pass two arguments. But the instructions do not say which arguments are meant to be passed.

How do I actually initiate the GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is just a general way of indicating a command prompt in Linux / UNIX systems.
It would basically be your `C:\>` prompt in Windows.  It's not something you type out to get your installation working.

If you're on Windows and have never installed a python package using *pip* before, open up a Windows console or command line terminal (You can click Start Menu, Run, then type "cmd" and press Enter to open a Windows console). Then follow these instructions first to install [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) on your system:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

After pip is installed on your system, then you can run the commands in your Windows console as instructed by the Bugjar installation guide (minus the `$` signs).